# Any way to push notification to app using FCM from Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have set up my app (client) that can be able to receive push notification from FCM by calling
 `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`
using Advanced Rest Client.

I have all the SenderID, Server Key and Device Token available.

Now I need to write a backend Java program using Eclipse to push notifications to my phone.

How can I do that?

*** my app is developed using Appcelerator Titanium

Comment: Hi user3051673, I strongly recommend you using Android Studio because the Eclipse Android plug-in is deprecated. You will get a better way to do it if you use it (It's very friendly)

Comment: @user3051673 Android studio is best for android development u can simply configure any lib by gradle.